# This must be a easy answer but, I've reached the point to ask. VB.NET comparing 4 string numbers including time

Tags: vb.net, string, datetime, datagridview, compare

This is part of the loop through a datagridview. I need to compare the string CallBackTime which is in HHmmss format to a defined time 6:00 PM ( 180000 ) so if CallBackTime is Greater than 180000 it is skipped and not added to datagridview. This part works fine.

In that same statement I need to also compare the current time HHmmss  vs CallBackTime and if that CallBackTime is 1hr less then current time do not add to datagridview. All other conditions can be added.

What I have so far is this:

```
If CallBackTime > 180000 Or CallBackTime < DateTime.Now.ToString("HHmmss") Then
```

The section after Or does not work as those are still added.

Any ideas?

Comment: please update your title to be a summary of your question; that one line of code makes little sense - the first comparison treats `CallBackTime` as a numeric, the second as a string. what is the actual datatype of `CallBackTime`?  Use `Option Strict On`

Comment: CallBackTime datatype = string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DateTime.Now is a DateTime instance. So every method available for a DateTime are usable on Now.
Including [AddHours](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addhours(v=vs.110).aspx) with a negative value

```
If CallBackTime > "180000" OrElse CallBackTime < DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1).ToString("HHmmss")
```

Also to avoid an unnecessary evaluation of the expression AddHours when the first condition is satisfied I suggest to use [OrElse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ea1sssb2.aspx) short circuit evaluation feature

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I have made the code change and will test tonight and eval. Makes better sense after you explained.